# Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxMin, Version=4.97.4951.28478,

Tags: c#, jquery

I'm working with ASP.net 4.0. from nut get manager. I updated jQuery and Json and this dll comes with it. But suddenly it stops responding and after successfully built with project this error error.

How do I fix this error?

> Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxMin, Version=4.97.4951.28478, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxMin, Version=4.97.4951.28478, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'AjaxMin, Version=4.97.4951.28478, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information ===
>    LOG: User = PC-DSC1\Administrator
>    LOG: DisplayName = AjaxMin, Version=4.97.4951.28478, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f
>        (Fully-specified)
>       LOG: Appbase = file:///F:/CRM/
>       LOG: Initial PrivatePath = F:\CRM\bin
>       Calling assembly : AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e.
>       ===
>       LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>       LOG: Using application configuration file: F:\CRM\web.config
>       LOG: Using host configuration file: 
>       LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>       LOG: Post-policy reference: AjaxMin, Version=4.97.4951.28478, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21ef50ce11b5d80f
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/crm/5f33c2bc/4717f3e7/AjaxMin.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/crm/5f33c2bc/4717f3e7/AjaxMin/AjaxMin.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///F:/CRM/bin/AjaxMin.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///F:/CRM/bin/AjaxMin/AjaxMin.DLL.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/crm/5f33c2bc/4717f3e7/AjaxMin.EXE.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/crm/5f33c2bc/4717f3e7/AjaxMin/AjaxMin.EXE.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///F:/CRM/bin/AjaxMin.EXE.
>       LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///F:/CRM/bin/AjaxMin/AjaxMin.EXE.

Answer (score 4):

Put AjaxMin.dll into your project bin folder from AjaxControlToolkit.Binary.NET40. problem will solved.
-preetam jakhmola

Answer (score 4):

Hi you have to install Ajax Min, go through following procedure

Go to Visual Studio > Tools> NuGet Package manager > Package Manager Console

write

PM> Install-Package AjaxMin

Press Enter.

That's all run your program :) Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was local user permissions issue. Here is how I fixed it:

1. Locate your application folder.
2. Right-click and select properties
3. Go to Security tab and see if <*YOURSERVERNAME*>/Users are listed
4. If not, add them with default permissions